# android force lauch activity in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I'm trying to launch MyActivity in landscape mode. The problem is that it is currently being launched in portrait mode an then it  goes to landscape mode.

I have defined MyActivity in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myproject.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:taskAffinity="com.myproject"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

**Is there any way to force the activity to be launched right into landscape mode?**

Comment: this is just a trick you might try, replace the main_layout.xml from `layout` folder to `layout-land` folder

Comment: @Naveen I'm still getting the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding the `onConfigurationChanged` method.

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. The activity is first created in portrait mode and then onConfigurationChanged is called and newConfig.orientation is landscape so it is rotated.

Comment: Hmm.. strange... its working for me. Have you tried using  `setRequestedOrientation()` inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: Yes, but still getting the same result. I've tried keeping the screen orientation configuration in the manifest and calling setContentView in onConfigurationChanged. That almost solves my problem. It is the closest solution I've found so far, so I'm marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: But what happens on more recent versions of Android that do start in the requested orientation first time? Will onConfigurationChanged get called at all? (I have the same issue, but it only applies to Android 2.x devices...)

Comment: There is no need to use onConfigurationChanged if activity start in the requested orientation first time.

Answer (score 2):

You need both parts to guarantee performance.

In `MainActivity.java`, put the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

And then in `AndroidManifest.xml`, include the following to prevent configuration changes:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myproject.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Below example works:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Me = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. At `AndroidManifest.xml`, in `<activity>` you want to force launch in landscape mode, add `android:screenOrientation="locked"`.
2. In `onCreate` of the `Activity` you want to force launch in landscape mode, add `requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE`

Explain:

- When you start an Activity, by **default** `Activity` will get the current orientation of your device, if your device is portrait, Activity is portrait. If your device is landscape, Activity is landscape. So, you need to locked orientation first.
- Then you need to set orientation in onCreate of the Activity, If you don't do that, the app will be crashed.
- You can also set orientation in `onStart`, `onResume`, but If you just need to set the orientation for one time, so just set on `onCreate`.